# Eliminating duplicate rows in subquery when calculating sum

Tags: sql

I am having troubles to get correct values for sumSquare which is calculated column in following query:

```
SELECT 
 building_type, 
 COUNT(distinct building.id) as buildingCount, 
 SUM(squareTable.sumSquare) as sumSquare, 

FROM building 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT building_id, SUM(square) as sumSquare  
  FROM building_square 
  WHERE (square >= '500')  
  GROUP BY building_id
) squareTable on (squareTable.building_id = building.id) 

JOIN building_square ON (building_square.building_id = building.id)

WHERE building_square.square >= '500'

GROUP BY building_type
```

building_type is column from building table (f.e. some of the types are: house, apartment...), i need to group by building type.
Also i have relation 1:N between building and building_square tables. In main query in where clause i need to filter by square which is column from building_square table.

I quess that problem is that i am joining building_square table in main query as i need to filter on some fields from that table, while i also use subquery that calculates sum of squares for particular building. As a result in sum i am counting some rows more than one time.
How to calculate sum of squares in subquery only for distinct building_id?

Comment: You will always have this problem with JOIN where there is a one-to-many relationship.  The trick is to remove that by reducing the "many" side.  A subquery may work well for you, or a CTE if your RDBMS supports that.  Please clarify which RDBMS (Oracle, MSSQL, ...) and what version you're using and you will get better answers.

Comment: Hi, I am using MSSQL. Problem is that i need to use fields from joined table in main query where clause.

Comment: It would help to have some more detail about your table structures. I'm unclear on which table `building_type` comes from. Table aliases and fully-qualified field names will help us and your future self! You say above that you need fields from joined table ... which fields from which table?

Comment: I may be missing something (see above) but I don't understand why you need the `WHERE` clause with `>=500` when this is handled in the subquery. Couldn't it also be an `INNER JOIN` to the subquery? I also don't like that you have the 500 surrounded by quote marks. It makes me worry that the number is stored as text. If so `'60'` would be "greater than" `'500'`

Comment: I'm guessing it's a `LEFT JOIN` to the subquery because a building may have no `square` values that are at least 500? If this is a query that's getting the sum of all squares over 500, and then we're only showing rows for which that's true, then an `INNER JOIN` to the subquery by itself ought to suffice? I think what we need here is a definition of the "business problem". That is, rather than telling us how you're trying to join everything together, tell us what you're trying to accomplish?